# Show value from database in array

Tags: database, postgresql, arraylist

I want to display entire content of my database table on html page.I am trying to fetch record from database first and store in ArrayList. What is the best way to do it in java using PostgreSql database ??????

Comment: try making your websites responsive maybe?

Comment: Further to @KoustavRay comment, you can see that the Google's website looks good because it responsive.

Comment: Correct but the main page where the div is being hosted is not responsive..plus it has overflow enabled..

Comment: I guess this can be solved with CSS. Having a look at your code would help to understand how to fix this. Can you provide this?

Comment: Yes........of course @  Pierre C

Answer (score 1):

You are using iframes to embed those “previews”, I assume?

In that case, you could achieve this by making the iframe element itself larger, and then use `transform: scale()` to scale it down again to the target size.

Check the following example – I used `example.com` for the iframe content, that site is not responsive, as you can see in the first 200px*200px iframe.

The second iframe is 500px*500px – and scaled down by a factor of `.4`, which is effectively 200px again. Since scaling an element down this way still leaves the space it would have taken originally reserved, it is placed inside a div element that cuts of that overflow.

```css
iframe, #i2 { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#i2 { overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; }
#i2 iframe { width: 500px; height: 500px; transform:scale(.4); transform-origin: top left; }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com/">
</iframe>

<div id="i2">
<iframe src="https://example.com/">
</iframe>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5hk9m446/

---

One thing you should be aware of, is that this will not work for just any website. Via the `X-Frame-Options` header websites can tell the browser, that they don’t *want* to be displayed in (i)frames on a different domain. In that case, you can’t do it client-side with iframes; you probably have to render a preview as an image server-side or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Transforms can help you to downscale iframes.
See this example
http://jsbin.com/wiperebifa/edit?html,css,output

Please also notice with iframes your mouse events are targeted to those pages.
You can use glass pane(s) over the iframes to capture these events or alternatively you can hide iframes and display their content with canvas.

Comment: is it possible to do it using div tag only instead of iframe .......@Nick Rassadin

Comment: nop... iframe is only way to load site and render it. alternatively you can use Selenium Webdriver to render screenshot images at server side.